# javascript - Using ctx.drawImage to show image inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

It does not show the image, I tried in all possible ways I cannot figure out how. How should I do to :

1) How  to create a new object object('20','X',250,100,'img'); and specify which picture I want to use it? img.player or img.player.src or just img?
2) How to iterate through the objectArray displaying them all in the canvas?

```js
15index.html: 38 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage'
on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="ctx" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

  <script>
    var WIDTH = 500;
    var HEIGHT = 500;
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
    ctx.font = '30px Arial';

    var img = {};

    img.player = new Image();
    img.player.src = "FireMonster.png"

    var objectArray = {};

    function object(id, name, x, y, img) {

      var object3 = {
        x: x,
        y: y,
        name: name,
        id: id,
        img: img,

      };

      objectArray[id] = object3;
    }

    object('20', 'X', 250, 100, 'img');
    object('21', 'P', 150, 150, 'img');

    drawingObject = function(something) {

      ctx.drawImage(something.img, something.x, something.y);

    }

    update = function() {

      for (var x in objectArray) {

        drawingObject(objectArray[x]);

      }
    }


    setInterval(update, 40);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the text of `'img'` to the `object` `function` instead of an `Image` object. Try this instead:

```
object('20', 'X', 250, 100, img.player);
object('21', 'P', 150, 150, img.player);
```

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 of CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.
drawingObject()
update()

Thanks for the answer this is the error code on Firefox.

Comment: On Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getContext is not a function

Comment: @Francesco, can you provide a jsFiddle for your problem or at least paste your html? Without your html it is impossible to determine why do you get the second error.